# MP3 player, that remembers current possition in all playlists or folders

Tags: applications, music-player

Is there any MP3 player out there, that would remember current file and position in that file, not only for currently played playlist / folder, but also in all playlists / folders, that are added to it?

I know, that remembering file and position in an active playlist, which is essential for listening to audiobooks, is offered by many MP3 players available for Android. But, that's not enough for me.

I'm looking for a player that will:

- support multiple playlists at once (with optional easy switch between them),
- remember file and position for all playlists and restore / rest it on each switch.

I tried system player, Winamp and [Simple Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.impulseapps.simplemusicfree). All of them lack second option. Once user switches to a new playlist, player begins to play it from the very first file and from its beginning.

I need this feature, because I'm listening to more than one audiobook simultaneously.

I know, that software recommendations are not much welcome to this site (or to any in SE network). But, I'm asking about very specific feature of an MP3 player. So, I treat this question not like *recommend me a software*, but rather as *tell me, if there is anyone out there, that has this feature, or should I code it myself*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is.
[MortPlayer Audio Books](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.stohelit.audiobookplayer) and [Smart AudioBook Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ak.alizandro.smartaudiobookplayer) have both been verified by me to have asked feature implemented.

Some details:

- [MortPlayer Audio Books](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.stohelit.audiobookplayer) is completely free (it displays ads, but these can be... disabled in settings), but offers an enormous number of options, settings and preferences, which can overwhelm many of fresh users; it is also based on skins, with many skins having... well... not to good UI, look & feel,
- [Smart AudioBook Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ak.alizandro.smartaudiobookplayer) is much simplier and offers more clean, standard UI, but it is not free. It comes with 30-days trial offering all options, after which it must be purchased for $2 or will block most extra options and features.

Both players have the most desired option. You can jump between folders or around media library and every time you open up a folder (book), that was opened by you before, you will always start listening from the position, you left it, not from the beginning.

There are probably many more audio players for Android, that supports these feature. Only, to find them,  one must search for *audiobook player*, not for *MP3 player*, as I did previously.

Answer (score 1):

Free ones:

[MortPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=mortplayer&c=apps&hl=en) ( I use this )

[Poweramp player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer)

[DoubleTwist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doubleTwist.androidPlayer&hl=en)

[Smart Audiobook Player 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fameoflight.husky&hl=en)

NRG Player

Comment: Your list is longer than mine, but to have your answer accepted you must extend it with a similar programs descriptions as I did. Say something about pros, cons etc.

Comment: Please note that [Poweramp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer) is not a free app. You must pay US$3.99 after the 14-day trial expires.