# MP3 player occasionally resets playlist

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, mp3-player

I'm using the standard MP3 player on Android 4.3. Whenever I listen to long pieces of music and I pause for several minutes and/or unplug the headphones (not sure of the exact cause), the playlist will just reset itself. This causes

- the active track to reset, which is very annoying for long tracks, and
- the shuffled playlist to reset, so that many tracks will be played twice.

Is there a way to make the player just remember the shuffled playlist as well as the active track position, no matter how long I don't use it?

I could not find a setting in the standard player to prevent it from resetting. [This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83499/mp3-player-that-remembers-current-possition-in-all-playlists-or-folders) indicates that for more *memory capacity* I would need a different player than the standard one, but I don't need it to keep track of several audiobooks or something.

Can this be achieved with the standard player, or do I really need another player, and if so, which one could it be? [Another question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/114523/android-music-player-does-the-default-music-player-program-store-the-timesta) deals with the logging of timestamps (which could solve that aspect), but it doesn't have an answer yet.

I'm not very skilled with Android, so please tell me in case I forgot to mention something.

edit: One reason why I use the standard player is that it's capable of playing very many formats which other players cannot, such as *.flac, .wma, .m4a, .mka*